# Binary image code size comparison between Cocoa Touch Static Library and DLL dynamic library

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, size

I am migrating a C++ dynamic DLL library from Windows OS to iOS with static library(.a).
And some issues come up about the binary image size.
Here are some data I got.

Image size:

dynamic library (DLL compiled in Windows OS) : 1.4M

static library(.a,complied with Touch Static Library): 34M.

I checked each complied C++ source file between 'Obj' and 'o'. The size of them are almost same.while,after linked them together,the size of DLL is 1.4M, while the '.a' image size is 34M.It seems image size of '.a' approximate to the summation of all the '.o' files.

Is there any suggestion and guideline for migration C++ code to iOS?,especially in image size.

Is there any link flag for compiling C++ source code in Cocoa Touch Static Library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix-based systems (including iOS), a ".a" file is simply an archive (`man 5 ar`) combining a bunch of ".o" files in a single unit (possibly with the inclusion of a symbol table). So, your observation the size of the ".a" file is the summation of the ".o" files is exactly correct.

When you link an application against a ".a" file, the final executable will include only the elements of the ".a" file that are actually referenced.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. It reminded me of the final executable APP is the only package that need install onto User's device. Because in iOS,all the library are static link against with main APP.